# DRY routes with different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How do can I DRY my routes that look like this

```
  post 'products/sum', to: 'product#sum'
  post 'products/subtract', to: 'product#subtract'
  post 'cars/sum', to: 'car#sum'
  post 'cars/subtract', to: 'car#subtract'
  post 'houses/sum', to: 'house#sum'
  post 'houses/subtract', to: 'house#subtract'
```

To something like

```
  post '%w{products,cars,houses}/%{sum subtract}', to: '%w{products,cars,houses}#%{sum subtract}'
```

Any how I just want to know if above routes are DRYable and if yes how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Just one option

```
%i(products cars houses).each do |item|
  resource item, only: [] do
    post :sum
    post :subtract
  end
end
```

This produces

```
➜ rake routes | grep -E "(house|car|product)"

     sum_products POST   /products/sum(.:format)         products#sum
subtract_products POST   /products/subtract(.:format)    products#subtract
         sum_cars POST   /cars/sum(.:format)             cars#sum
    subtract_cars POST   /cars/subtract(.:format)        cars#subtract
       sum_houses POST   /houses/sum(.:format)           houses#sum
  subtract_houses POST   /houses/subtract(.:format)      houses#subtract
```

Comment: what is this only: doing?

Comment: `resource` is going to set a bunch of default routes for the `:house`, `:car`, and `:product. The `:only` option lets you specify a whitelist of those defaults to use. If I want only create/update/destroy, I can do `only: [:create, :update, :destroy]`. Since you didn't specify wanting anything, `resource` is used to get the route prefix you want, and `only: []` says "don't give me any other default resource routes".